# How do we show the options bar options vertically in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-optionsmenu

I am using two option menus in my `Layout`. I am opening them with different button clicks using

```
openOptionsMenu();
```

I have 5 items in my options menu, when i call it, it pops up in Grid. ( table like click ) I want them vertically one on another, what should i do?

Comment: If you deploy the same application on android 4.0+, it would be shown `Vertically` itself. AFAIK below 2.3 it's shown as horizontal.

Comment: It is showing in GRID VIEW only on the main_activity page and on other activities it is showing vertically. PS: i am deploying it on 4.0+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got my problem solved from here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/173121/Android-Menus-My-Way
Download the source code for complete understanding. cheers :)